# Uiimageview border is distroted with zigzag border?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, border, transformation

I am using UICollectionView in my iphone app and i have somwhat modified the uicollection view for horizinatcl rotation in circular way. following is the image.[image]

Now what i am facing problem is why the border of this images is distroted with zigzaging border.
i don't know why this coming and for what reason. anyone knows how can i solve the distrotation of this images border.

any help would be appreciable..

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the code to create the image and imageview, add a border and round the corners:

```
// Define a new image object
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lake.png"];

// Define a new image view
  UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 157, 125)];

// Set image in imageview and add to view
  [imgView setImage:image];
  [[self view] addSubview:imgView];

// Create a white border with defined width
  imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;

// Set image corner radius
  imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

// To enable corners to be "clipped"
  [imgView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with your image

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

If need, change **UIEdgeInsets** values...

Answer (score 0):

Rasterization should fix this issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize

```
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES; 
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```